# Sending Push Through Parse API Results in 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python, ios, rest, parse-platform, python-requests

I'm trying to send push notifications from our python backend to an iOS mobile app through Parse. Everything on the iOS side is configured but when I make the request to the Parse API I get a `401 Unauthorized` response.

```
headers = {'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'MY_API_KEY', 'X-Parse-Master-Key': 'MY_MASTER_KEY', 'Content-Type': 'content/json', 'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'MY_APPLICATION_ID'}

params = {'channels': ['general'], 'data': {'alert': 'Test push'}}

url = 'http://api.parse.com/1/push'

r = requests.post(url, params = params, headers = headers)

print r.status_code
>> 401
```

Comment: what does `r.text` say?

Comment: `u'{"error":"unauthorized"}\n'`

Comment: You are not sending the app id in the headers https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications-sending-pushes

Comment: That is what this header is `X-Parse-Application-Id`, should it be something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = "https://api.parse.com:443/1/push"    
params = {'channels': ['general'], 'data': {'alert': 'Test push'}}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
           "X-Parse-Application-Id":"APP_ID",   
           "X-Parse-REST-API-Key":"API_KEY"}

r = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(params), headers = headers)

r.status_code
>>>200

r.text
>>>u'{"result":true}\n'
```

What was needed to use the `requests` function instead of httplib with Python and Parse.com are here:

1. Url needs port number with https. (Taken from parse examples using httplib)
2. Headers needs `Content-Type : application/json` for POST as said in [Parse Rest API Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#quick-reference-request-format)
3. `Params` has to be passed as a request body instead of url encoded